# How to remove last comma in a given string?

Tags: excel, vba

I tried with below code, but unable to remove comma. Please help.

```
Sub removelastcommas()

    Dim i As Integer, str As String

    str = Range("A1")

    For i = Len(str) To 1
        If Mid(str, i, 1) <> "," Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Range("b1") = Left(str, i)

End Sub
```

Comment: `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option, using `InStrRev` function (without using a loop) is:

```
Sub removelastcommas()

    Dim i As Integer, str As String
    str = Range("A1")

    i = InStrRev(str, ",")
    ' comma found in A1
    If i > 0 Then
        Range("B1") = Left(str, i - 1) & Right(str, Len(str) - i)
    Else ' comma not found in A1
        Range("B1") = Range("A1")
    End If  

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This will remove the last comma from a string:

```
Sub removelastcommas()
    Dim i As Integer, str As String
    str = Range("A1")
        For i = Len(str) To 1 Step -1
            If Mid(str, i, 1) = "," Then
                Range("B1").Value = Left(str, i - 1) & Mid(str, i + 1)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next i
End Sub
```

[image]